# Discord.net how to mention roles

Tags: discord.net

How can I mention guild roles in C# with the Discord.net library?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider adding a bit more content to your question. As it currently stands it is not very clear nor helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
MentionUtils.MentionRole(id)
```

Comment: Or use the `.Mention` property on the `Role` object

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to use the raw mention of a role, that is in fact the content of the `.Mention` property in a role object.

The format is the following:

`<@&ROLE_ID>`

It differs from mentioning an individual user by the `&` character, that specifies it's mentioning the role, not a user.

You can get the role ID from the `.ID` property, or by right clicking the role in the roles list, if you want to hardcode it.

Example command of mentioning a role by the name:

```cs
        [Command("mention")]
        public async Task MentionRole(string name)
        {
            SocketRole role = Context.Guild.Roles.First(x => x.Name == name); //Get the first role that matches the name provided

            await ReplyAsync($"<@&{role.Id}>"); //Format the string that mentions the role (ex. <@&739515238742753371>)
            await ReplyAsync(role.Mention); //Optionally, you can use the integrated property that returns the exact same string as we formatted above

            //The mention is instantly sent as a reply to the command
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can with `iRole`

```
[Command("roleinfo")]
    public async Task mentionRoleAsync(IRole role)
    {

        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        embed.WithDescription("Role ID : " + role.Id + Environment.NewLine + "Role Name : " + role.Name + Environment.NewLine + "Role Mention : " + role.Mention + Environment.NewLine + "Role Mention : " + role.Mention + Environment.NewLine + "Role Color : " + role.Color.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Role Created at : " + role.CreatedAt);
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);

    }
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Thats an example, you have to use IRole and if you want to mention it then just send in the message: <&ROLEID>

```
[Command("role")]
    public async Task mentionRoleAsync(IRole role)
    {

        var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithTitle("Role Infos")
        .WithDescription($"Role ID{role.Id} \n Name: {role.Name}");


    }
```